# Why is there only a single bias per neuron in the Neural Network?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, data-science, artificial-intelligence

What happens if we associate multiple biases with a single neuron in the Neural Network? Will it allows approximating more complex functions?

Comment: please present the equation for a fully connected neuron, which has some weights and a bias, including activation function. then please suggest an equation that uses multiple biases.

Comment: Please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 1):

No, why should it? If you add more bias units you can always summarize them in one single bias.